# Powershell passing variables to remote script

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have the following cmd file:-

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit E:\wwwroot\domains\processes\AddDirectory.ps1 -Param testdomain.co.uk
```

which goes through to:-

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.25
$script = {
Param($Param1)
set-executionpolicy unrestricted -force

# Set Variables
$domain = $Param1
$sitepath = "e:\domains\" + $domain

# Check for physical path
if (-not (Test-Path -path $sitePath))
{
New-Item -Path $sitepath -type directory 
New-Item -Path $sitepath\wwwroot -type directory 
}
set-executionpolicy restricted -force     
}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $script
```

But it just runs but does nothing.

If I declare the $domain variable as $domain = 'testdomain.co.uk' it works but it doesn't want to pass through the var from the cmd file. What am I doing wrong? I've tried to put it in the Invoke-Command as -ArgumentsList -$Param1 but that doesn't work either.....

Any ideas greatfully received

Thanks
Paul

Update - I've updated my code as per below but getting same issue:-

```
param($domainName)
$script = {
    Param($Param1)
    set-executionpolicy unrestricted -force
    # Set Variables
    $domain = $Param1
    $sitepath = "e:\domains\" + $domain
    # Check for physical path
    if (-not (Test-Path -path $sitePath))
    {
        New-Item -Path $sitepath -type directory
        New-Item -Path $sitepath\wwwroot -type directory
        New-Item -Path $sitepath\db -type directory
        New-Item -Path $sitepath\stats -type directory
    }
    set-executionpolicy restricted -force
}

$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.25

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $domainName
```

Comment: Is e: a local or networked mapped drive.  If it is the latter, you may be running into a double-hop authentication issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a param block in the script, the argument you pass to the file will be assign to $domainName and you will use it to pass the value to the scriptblock    :

```
PowerShell.exe -noexit E:\wwwroot\domains\processes\AddDirectory.ps1 testdomain.co.uk


# script file

param($domainName)

$script = {
    Param($Param1)

    ...
    $domain = $Param1
    ...   
}

$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.25
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $domainName
```

Comment: ok I've out the following code in now but it doesn't work - the file runs but nothing happens:-

Comment: param($domainName)
$script = {
Param($Param1)
set-executionpolicy unrestricted -force
# Set Variables
$domain = $Param1
$sitepath = "e:\domains\" + $domain
# Check for physical path
if (-not (Test-Path -path $sitePath))
{
  New-Item -Path $sitepath -type directory 
  New-Item -Path $sitepath\wwwroot -type directory 
  New-Item -Path $sitepath\db -type directory 
  New-Item -Path $sitepath\stats -type directory 
}

set-executionpolicy restricted -force
       
}

$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.25

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $domainName

Comment: Hi - updated code in initial question as it wont let me format correctly in the comments box...

Comment: This is working now - in my cmd file I had *.ps1 -param testdomain.co.uk. I've taken out the -param and it works - many thanks!