# Variable is not sent to remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the code below that I have been working on and I have an issue, I can not get it to send the variable message to the computer, if I take out the variable it works but that is not what I was trying to accomplish with it.

```
Function Send-PopupMessage {
    #Requires -Version 2.0 
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$Message
    )

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Scriptblock {
        $CmdMessage = "msg.exe * $Message"
        Write-Host $CmdMessage
        $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
    }
}
```

This is not the same as the [question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036327/powershell-passing-variables-to-remote-script) because I am in a session to another computer using PSWA so I am not able to start another session from this. Also even when I changed my code to be more like the one in the "Duplicate" question I am still getting the same results that the cmd being sent to the other computer is

> msg.exe * ''
>    instead of 
>   msg.exe * 'Test Message'

Comment: In short: use `$using:Message` in order to reference the _local_ definition of `$Message`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell script blocks are not lexical closures by default.  The scriptblock passed to Invoke-Command does not save the current value of the `$Message` parameter when being run on the other computer.

When the block is run in the remote session, it is using the current value of `$Message` in that session.  Because that variable is most likely `$null`, the message is omitted from your command.

Use the `$using:variable` syntax [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35492437) to capture the value of `$Message`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Scriptblock {
    $CmdMessage = "msg.exe * $using:Message"
    Write-Host $CmdMessage
    $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
}
```

The `$using:variable` syntax only works when invoking a block on a remote computer.  If you need to capture variables in a scriptblock for local execution, instead call `GetNewClosure()` on the ScriptBlock.

```
$Message = "Hey there."
$closure = {
    $CmdMessage = "msg.exe * $Message"
    Write-Host $CmdMessage
    $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
}.GetNewClosure()

$Message = $null
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $closure
```

Comment: While your explanation is correct, I don't think your solution works: assuming that your local machine is set up for remoting, contrast the following commands (only the last one works):
`$foo = 'bar'; icm -computername . { $foo }` vs. `$foo = 'bar'; icm -computername . { $foo }.GetNewClosure()` vs. `$foo = 'bar'; icm -computername . { $using:foo }`

Comment: AFAIK, for remote invocation `Invoke-Command` is ignore any module `ScriptBlock` is attached to, so `GetNewClosure()` useless here.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the `$using:var` syntax, though I agree that probably makes this a dupe.  Thanks @mklement0

Comment: If you don't use `-ComputerName` with `Invoke-Command`, local execution in the current scope is performed, where local variables are directly accessible - no need for `.GetNewClosure()`. Compare `$foo = 'bar'; icm  { $foo }`, which is effectively the same as `$foo = 'bar'; & { $foo }`. I'm unclear on when `.GetNewClosure()` is actually needed.

Comment: GetNewClosure saves the state of the variables when it is called.  In the example above, the `$Message` variable is set to null, but the scriptblock invocation still uses its old value.  I have used this to save variable state for later execution.

Comment: That worked like a charm, and yes I think you are right that my question might be a duplicate, but thank you for taking the time to explain the answer!